# Is there any way to store a particular response attribute to a variable and then use it in another feature file's request payload using Karate?

Tags: karate, junit4, karate-call-single

I want to store reponse's Id and Token in 2 variables i.e. responseId and responseToken and then use the responseId in 2nd feature file's request payload.

Feature File 1:

Feature: User Registration

Background:
* url 'https://test.com'

Scenario: Register a New User
Given path 'register'
{

```
"email": "abc123@gmail.com",
"password": "Abc123",
"firstName": "Abc",
"lastName": "API",
"gender": "M",
```

}
When method post
Then status 200
* def responseToken = response.token
* def responseId = response.id
* print 'Token:', responseToken
* print 'User ID:', responseId

Now I want to use this responseId's value in 2nd feature file
Feature: Validation

```
Background:

    * call read('feature1.feature') {responseId: '#(responseId)'}
    * url 'https://test.com'

Scenario: Send OTP
    Given path 'sendOTP'
    * def requestPayload =
    """
    {
    "type": "email",
    "action": "login",
    "device": "Abc"
        }
    """
    * request.userId = {responseId: '#(responseId)'}
    And request requestPayload
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

Result :  Getting error on * call read('feature1.feature') {responseId: '#(responseId)'}